# Ngx Pagination-Jump to Specific Page

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I would like to create ngx pagination in angular 8 specifically jump to exact page.

Ex Go To (Text box comes here) . I have 10 pages when user tries to enter 3 it should move to page 3.I'm pretty new to Angular.your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer official question raised by someone [here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/issues/291)

Also, check docs from library [paginationcontrolsdirective](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination#paginationcontrolsdirective)

Library provide the event called `setCurrent(val)` so, you can pass input value by button click

I hope you are clear with the provided solution